# Giving an argument list as file names extracted from another tab separated file

Tags: awk

I have a tab delimited file as below. The first column represents the list of file names without `.txt` extension which I want to pass as an argument list to another `awk` command.

```
File1   abcd    xyz 234 pqr
File2   abcd    xyz 234 pqr
File3   abcd    xyz 234 pqr
File4   abcd    xyz 234 pqr
```

e.g. Assume this is my `awk` command, I want to pass arguments as

```
awk -F"\t" '---Commamd-----' File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt File4.txt >> Final.txt
```

So that it takes each row from 1st column with `".txt"` extention as input and create `Final.txt` output file. It should be noted that number of columns may vary each time.

I thought of creating it in bash script, but I am not able to provide correct arguments and append next row from 1st column as next argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by my understanding of your requirements, you want to use the tab-separated file to get the file names on column 1 and you want to add `.txt` extension to them and pass it to another file. Firstly use `mapfile` to get the names from the tab-separated file

```
mapfile -t fileNames < <(awk -v FS="\t" '{print $1}' tabfile)
```

Now to pass this as an argument list to another function, all you need to do is use this quoted array by suffixing the `.txt` extension to it

```
awk ... "${fileNames[@]/%/.txt}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure here as it is not clear. Based on your statement that you want to get file names from 1 `awk` and pass it to another `awk` following could be tried.

```
awk '{print $0}' <(awk 'NF{print $1".txt"}' Input_file)
```

So in spite of `print $0` you could do your operations here, I just printed it to see if file names are coming proper or not. Also add `-F="\t"` in 2nd `awk` in case your Input_file is TAB delimited and could change `$1` to any other field in case file names are not on first column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk

```
awk '{file=$1".txt";while (getline<file == 1)print $2}' infile
```

---

> append .txt on all $1 of infile to get the filename like File2.txt
>   print $2 of this file if it exist.